# ¿Cómo actualizar una tabla a partir de la carga de datos en otra en Django?

Tags: python, djangorestframework, geolocalización

Estoy intentando crear una *API* que guarde datos enviados desde un *bus*. Cada dato que envía este *bus* se guardará en una tabla, la cual irá creciendo rápidamente. Tengo un modelo que es el siguiente:

```
class Bus_Datos(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    viaje_inicio = models.ForeignKey(Viaje_Incio, on_delete = models.CASCADE)#identificador de viaje proveido por el servidor al raspberry

    time_rasp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False) #tiempo que provee el raspberry
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)#tiempo en el que se guarda en la base de datos
    location_bus = models.PointField()#locacion del bus

    siniestro_bus = models.BooleanField(default = False)#boton de siniestro en el bus
    sensor_asiento = models.BooleanField(default = False)#sensor del asiento para personas con discapacidad
    estado_viaje = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ESTADOS_VIAJE, default='PY')#identificador de viaje proveido por el servidor al raspberry

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Bus_Dato'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Bus_Datos'
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

El modelo guardará una excesiva cantidad de datos en la tabla `Bus_Datos`. Lo que yo necesito es que con cada carga de este modelo, se vaya creando y/o actualizando otra tabla llamada `Bus_Datos_Last`, en la cual solo deberán aparecer los ultimos datos cargados.

`viaje_inicio` sería lo que identificaría a cada uno los datos que necesitaré en la tabla `Bus_Datos_Last`.

La idea de crear otra tabla con las últimas posiciones, es poder consultar solo la tabla `Datos_Last`, a fin de mostrar eso en un mapa.

¿Cuál sería la función que a medida que se van registrando los datos en la tabla `Bus_Datos`, automáticamente los cree si no hay, o acutalice los datos en la tabla `Bus_Datos_Last` atendiendo al campo `viaje_inicio`

Comment: esto no lo tiene que hacer tu app web, esto lo tiene que hacer un script/programa/ETL  que vaya actualizando la base de datos lo que quieres es agregar una logica muy compleja a la peticion menos indicada

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia. Al final... cree la otra tabla... y al momento de cargar desde el cliente, tambien creo el registro en la tabla Bus_Datos_Last y luego, desde el cliente la voy actualizando. Solo que, esto implica enviar dos veces el dato desde el cliente, lo cual no es muy aceptable, pero a medida que vaya ganando un poco de expertice en el tema, publicare como quedo al final.